# Variables not printing as intended

Tags: batch-file

I was toying around with making an extended CMD. Functions aren't important here though. It is meant to run special commands only when + is detected, and when not it just prints the variable into console.

```
@set "maininput="
@set /p "mainInput= Enter in a command here ~ "
@set "SEALDETECT=%mainInput:~0,1%"
@if "%SEALDETECT%"=="+" goto SealConsole
%maininput%
```

This works ok for the most part, but if I enter "`echo %date%`" it just outputs "`%date%`" instead. I want it to actually echo the variable, like `"echo %date%`" would output the actual date

I'm pretty sure the problem is having a variable inside another variable. I need a way to get around this.

Comment: Your script doesn't show a `test` variable! If you have only shown a part of the script then I'd suggest you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46598080/edit) to include more of it. If you are entering `echo %test%` at the `Set/P` prompt then you may need to enter `echo %%test%%` to escape each of the percent characters

Comment: I changed the variable to the environment date variable.

Comment: You may still need to enter `echo %%date%%`

Comment: No luck. It just prints %%date%%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this problem. The simplest one is to Enable Delayed Expansion and then use `!var!` to show a variable value instead of `%var%`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo Use ^^^!var^^^! to show var value

:nextLine
set "maininput="
set /p "mainInput=Enter in a command here ~ "
if not defined maininput exit /B
set "SEALDETECT=%mainInput:~0,1%"
if "%SEALDETECT%"=="+" goto SealConsole
%maininput%
goto nextLine

:SealConsole
echo Special command: %maininput:~1%
goto nextLine
```

Example:

```
Use !var! to show var value
Enter in a command here ~ echo !date!
06/10/2017
Enter in a command here ~
```

Comment: @CrologMark: This is the only solution that after an `echo !date!` input it shows the current date, as requested. Perhaps I misunderstood something? **`:(`**

Comment: No, thank you, i misread the other one. I'm going to be using this one.
Thank you

Comment: Input `echo Oops^^^!` do display exclamation mark in `Oops!`